# Where are the circuit breakers on the 787?

Tags: aircraft-systems, electrical-system, boeing-787, circuit-breaker

[image]
([787](http://andystravelblog.boardingarea.com/2015/05/08/american-airlines-787-review/) left, [777](http://www.airliners.net/photo/Singapore-Airlines/Boeing-777-312/885702) right)

Normally found aft of the overhead panel, where are they on the Boeing 787?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> The cockpit is clean and uncluttered thanks to the absence of the large circuit breaker panels that we’re used to in traditional types. Almost all circuit breakers are ‘virtual’ and are accessed via the forward Multi-Functional Display (MFD).
>
> — [flight.org](http:////www.flight.org/boeing-787-a-pilots-perspective)

The 787 and its contemporaries have moved away from physical CB's and use virtual CB's instead.

> One of the more dramatic simplifications of the 787 flight deck is a result of the 787’s “more-electric” architecture. Remote power distribution allows for the use of [electronic circuit breakers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_relay), eliminating hundreds of physical circuit breakers from the flight deck. Flight crew awareness of system state is enhanced with visual information on every circuit interruption device, including those remotely located, via multifunction display (MFD) screens.
>
> The reduction in parts and improved design means lower operating costs and higher reliability. For example, the 787 requires just 13 line replaceable units (LRUs) to provide a full complement of flight deck display, communication, navigation, and surveillance capability. That’s about half as many LRUs as other models require for the same capability.
>
> — [boeing.com](http:////www.boeing.com/commercial/aeromagazine/articles/2012_q1/3/)

[image]
(Click image to enlarge) *Example of CB sorting by system and different states.*