# What is the working principle of VFG

Tags: electrical-system, electric-engine, electronics, static-electricity, frequency

How does the VFG make various frequencies? And while it makes the other value of frequency, how the generator apply consistent 400Hz to the other component?

Comment: What is VFG? Google brings up too many hits.

Comment: Does this previous answer help?  https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/36981/how-does-the-a350-380-operate-on-variable-frequency-ac-generators